# Sql Query Results formatting

Tags: sql-server

I am executing a query and I want the output as

```
CompanyType SFCount SNCount
Customer     47       3
Vendor       8        3
Internal     11       1
```

but the output is coming like:

[image]

Comment: Include your query and table structure as text, not an image.

Comment: please consider adding  expected result in formatted text. 
Also show us your current query attempt

Comment: Group by CompanyType should do the job.

Comment: What query you have tried?

Comment: some sample data and table structure would really help us help you

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your query up in a subquery and `sum()` the results:

```
 SELECT sub.CompanyType, sum(sub.sfcount) as sfcount, sum(sub.sncount) as sncount
 FROM ( 
        SELECT businesstype AS [CompanyType],
            count(*) AS [SFCount],
            '' AS [SNCount]
        FROM account
        WHERE businesstype IN ( 'Customer', 'Vendor', 'Internal')       )
        GROUP BY businesstype

        UNION

        SELECT 'Customer' AS [CompanyType],
            '' AS [SFCount],
            count(*) AS [SNCount]
        FROM sn_core_company
        WHERE customer = 1

        UNION

        SELECT 'Vendor' AS [CompanyType],
            '' AS [SFCount],
            count(*) AS [SNCount]
        FROM sn_core_company
        WHERE vendor = 1

        UNION

        SELECT 'Internal' AS [CompanyType],
            '' AS [SFCount],
            count(*) AS [SNCount]
        FROM sn_core_company
        WHERE u_internal = 1

 ) sub
 GROUP BY businesstype;
```

Answer (score -3):

Just add where condition in all select statements

where SFCount > 0 and SNCount>0 as per your requirement

Comment: This will not work. OP will end up getting 0 results rows back.